# VBA "Loop" within If Else statement

Tags: vba, loops, excel

Can anyone tell me why I would be getting a compile error: "Loop without do" for the following code.

```
Sub Burrito_log()

    Dim j As Long
    j = 1
    Do
        x = InputBox("How many burritos did you have today?")
        Cells(j, 2) = x
        Cells(j, 1) = Date
        j = j + 1

        ans = MsgBox("Burrito Log", vbYesNo, "Are you done inputting?")
        If ans = vbYes Then
            'Do nothing
        Else
            Loop
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Alexandre gave you the answer. I would highlight, also, that your `Loop` doesn't have a `break` clause. Be aware that if you never `Exit` your `Do` you will eat Burritos forever.

Comment: You have to close your `If` block before you can close your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After formating your code the error is obvious. Your `Loop` is located before your `End If`. Just move it after `End If`.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your code, it seems you want to loop only if the answer is "No".
The syntax you use is incorrect, you need to nest an `Exit Do` breaking clause in the `If` block but you cannot nest the `Loop` keyword inside. Here's how it should be:

```
Sub Burrito_log()

    Dim j As Long
    j = 1
    Do
        x = InputBox("How many burritos did you have today?")
        Cells(j, 2) = x
        Cells(j, 1) = Date
        j = j + 1

        ans = MsgBox("Burrito Log", vbYesNo, "Are you done inputting?")
        If ans = vbYes Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can avoid the `If` block by using the `While` keyword of the `Do Loop`:

```
Do While ans <> vbYes
    'no If block --> Exit Do needed
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
ans = MsgBox("Burrito Log", vbYesNo, "Are you done inputting?") 

If ans = vbYes Then Exit Do
Loop
```

I think this is what you were trying to do, but you had the syntax off a bit.

I would add more explanation, but I'm on my phone.

There's more info on loop syntax here http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html